# Carousel in Bootstrap not working

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

### Here is my code:

```
<head>
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial scale=1'>
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name='author' content="EvaBozh">
<link rel="icon" href='#'>
<title>Bootstrap 3.2.0</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome-4.2.0/font-awesome-4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<!-- Custom Styles for this Site -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/style.css" />
</head>
<body style="background-image: url('Assets/Images/Background.png')">

<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="3000">

<ol class="carousel-indicators">
<li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
<li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
<li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
</ol>

<div class="carousel-inner">
<div class="item active">
<img src="Assets/Images/1.jpg" alt="First">
<div class="carousel-caption">
<h1>Example Headline</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
<p><a class='btn btn-lg btn-primary' href='#' role='button'>Button [1]</a></p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="item">
<img src="Assets/Images/2.jpg" alt="Second">
<div class="carousel-caption">
<h1>Example Headline</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
<p><a class='btn btn-lg btn-primary' href='#' role='button'>Button [2]</a></p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="item">
<img src="Assets/Images/3.jpg" alt="Third">
<div class="carousel-caption">
<h1>Example Headline</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
<p><a class='btn btn-lg btn-primary' href='#' role='button'>Button [3]</a></p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- Controls -->
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#" role="button" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a>
<a class="right carousel-control" href="#" role="button" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
</div>

<script src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js'></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="twitter-bootstrap-v2/docs/assets/js/bootstrap-transition.js"></script>
</body>
```

---

Everything is working, except for, when I click on "glyphicon", it supposed to change the image. But it's not.. Can someone please help me with this and maybe change the code? Because I can't understand what the problem. I'm new at this so... !

Comment: Can you make jsfiddle?

Comment: Of course! Here it is:  http://jsfiddle.net/b3vfus25/

Comment: Check your image path is correct Or not.

Comment: Where is the fiddle link?

Comment: In my code or jsfiddle? If in my code than the path to my image is correct

Comment: Your project is live then please share URL

Comment: In jsfiddle it's working. [link](http://jsfiddle.net/EveBozh/3Le60nch/)   But in my website it's not working

Comment: You did not add the data target on the left and right buttons: http://jsfiddle.net/b3vfus25/2/ -- you should also indent your html so that you can read it easier. And change the names from example id to something your own.

Comment: What URL should I share? Sorry, if it's stupid question, it's just because i don't know English so well

Comment: First correct it with the data-target on the left and right. Indent the code, double check that all the divs etc., are closed.

Comment: I did everything, it's working now! Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using online source path of jquery then this path is not working, so you have to use this one. It will work for you.
    `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Thanks! I put in my code the script that you gave and it's working! Thank you, so much!

Answer (score 2):

[**Js Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/b3vfus25/1/)

made changes to contollers

```
 <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
 </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
  </a>
```

changed `href="#"` to `href="#carousel-example-generic"`